# Adding stuff to the UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have made one popover. Presently that popover is blank. I need to add 6 buttons to the popover. Pressing any of the 6 buttons, the app takes the user to the respective screen. I want to add those buttons in table view style. You can consider the image attached with it (check the popup with 6 options in the left side of the iPad). I want to do it in the same way. Guide me please.
Regards PC.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view controller, add a UITableView, implement it to show the cells correctly, make it the content of the popover controller.

Answer (score 2):

Open the **Xcode Organizer > Documentation** and search *UIPopoverController*. In the left sidebar, at the bottom, open 'Popovers' sample code project.

Basically you'll see that you need to create a `UIPopoverController` instance somewhere in your code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    /* 'contentCtrl' is an instance of UIViewController 
     * such as an UITableViewController
     */
    ...
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentCtrl];
    popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    ...
}
```

And show it at some point, such as when the user press a button:

```
- (IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame 
                             inView:self.view 
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                           animated:YES];
}
```

I'd suggest to study the sample. If you need help with the `UITableView` part, there are dozens of samples on the subject in the Documentation (and hundredths of questions in SO).